# AOSP 13 build variable PRODUCT_ART_TARGET_INCLUDE_DEBUG_BUILD not working

Tags: android-source, android-make

I want the package `com.android.art` in my eng build of AOSP instead of `com.android.art.debug` for performance reasons. I noticed this makefile code in `runtime_libart.mk`:

```
art_target_include_debug_build := $(PRODUCT_ART_TARGET_INCLUDE_DEBUG_BUILD)
ifneq (false,$(art_target_include_debug_build))
  ifneq (,$(filter eng,$(TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT)))
    art_target_include_debug_build := true
  endif
endif

ifeq (true,$(art_target_include_debug_build))
  PRODUCT_PACKAGES += com.android.art.debug
  apex_test_module := art-check-debug-apex-gen-fakebin
else
  PRODUCT_PACKAGES += com.android.art
  apex_test_module := art-check-release-apex-gen-fakebin
endif
```

So I added the following to the mk file for my device:

```
PRODUCT_ART_TARGET_INCLUDE_DEBUG_BUILD := false
```

But it doesn't work, I added some debugging to `runtime_libart.mk`:

```
$(warning PRODUCT_ART_TARGET_INCLUDE_DEBUG_BUILD is $(PRODUCT_ART_TARGET_INCLUDE_DEBUG_BUILD))
$(warning PRODUCT_NAME is $(PRODUCT_NAME))
$(warning BOARD_DYNAMIC_PARTITION_ENABLE is $(BOARD_DYNAMIC_PARTITION_ENABLE))
$(error stop)
```

and I see the following:

```
build/make/target/product/runtime_libart.mk:49: warning: PRODUCT_ART_TARGET_INCLUDE_DEBUG_BUILD is @inherit:build/make/target/product/default_art_config.mk
build/make/target/product/runtime_libart.mk:50: warning: PRODUCT_NAME is @inherit:build/make/target/product/default_art_config.mk
build/make/target/product/runtime_libart.mk:51: warning: BOARD_DYNAMIC_PARTITION_ENABLE is true
```

So just variables with `PRODUCT` are getting super strange values. How can I get `PRODUCT_ART_TARGET_INCLUDE_DEBUG_BUILD` to work?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to do it the right way and I just hacked the `runtime_libart.mk` in AOSP itself:

```
# Hack since PRODUCT_ART_TARGET_INCLUDE_DEBUG_BUILD isn't working in
# device makefiles, necessary because debug ART is really slow

art_target_include_debug_build := false

# Existing AOSP build script lines follow

ifeq (true,$(art_target_include_debug_build))
  PRODUCT_PACKAGES += com.android.art.debug
  apex_test_module := art-check-debug-apex-gen-fakebin
else
  PRODUCT_PACKAGES += com.android.art
  apex_test_module := art-check-release-apex-gen-fakebin
endif
```